# Using map() or similar function to return the array data in the following format

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, array.prototype.map

I have the following javascript array (I'm having fun with map() today) - I want to be able to return the `pages` data but have the `page id` as the key and the index for the position of that page within the pages array as the value. What am I doing wrong?

```
let result = [
  {
      "id": 10000089,
      "units": [
          {
              "id": 10000200,
              "pages": [
                  {
                      "id": 100000882
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "id": 10000340,
              "pages": [
                  {
                      "id": 100000912
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 100000915
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 100000919
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],
  }
];
```

```
// this is my attempt but doesn't return in the intended format below
result.flatMap(el => el.units.map((e, i) => (e.pages)));
```

Expected output

```
pages = [
  100000882 => 0,
  100000912 => 0,
  100000915 => 1,
  100000919 => 2,
]
```

Here is a stackblitz to the code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mc9rqe

Comment: The expected output is invalid. `pages` would have to be an object (or an array of objects). You want the ids with their index in the respective `pages` array. How is `.map(i, i) => (e.pages))` supposed to produce this output (you not even use the index `i`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output should be an `object` instead of an `array`. You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) for achieving the result.

```js
let result=[{id:10000089,units:[{id:10000200,pages:[{id:100000882}]},{id:10000340,pages:[{id:100000912},{id:100000915},{id:100000919}]}]}];

const pages = Object.fromEntries(
  result.flatMap(item => item.units.flatMap(unit => unit.pages.map((page,i) => ([page.id, i]))))
);
console.log(pages);
```

**Note that**, the `Object.fromEntries()` takes an array of arrays of a `[key, value]` pair and then converts them into an object. In your case the `page.id` would be the `key` and the `index` of the last map would be the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

In your data, `pages` is also an array of objects. So, you need to loop through each page as well.

- Using `Array.flat`

```js
let result=[{id:10000089,units:[{id:10000200,pages:[{id:100000882}]},{id:10000340,pages:[{id:100000912},{id:100000915},{id:100000919}]}]}];

const getFormattedData = data => {
  const res = data.map(datum => datum.units.map(unit => unit.pages.map(({ id }, i) => ({
    [id]: i
  }))));
  return res.flat(2);
}
console.log(getFormattedData(result));
```

- Using `Array.flatMap`

```js
let result=[{id:10000089,units:[{id:10000200,pages:[{id:100000882}]},{id:10000340,pages:[{id:100000912},{id:100000915},{id:100000919}]}]}];

const getFormattedData = data => {
  return data.flatMap(datum => datum.units.flatMap(unit => unit.pages.map(({ id }, i) => ({
    [id]: i
  }))));
}
console.log(getFormattedData(result));
```

Note that both of the above methods will result in Array of objects.